# Delay slideDown()/slideUp() - jquery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating I am creating a drop down which I want to delay about 250 ms so that it's not triggered when someone quickly scrolls across the button.

Here's my current code. I tried using the delay() method but it's not going well.

```
$(".deltaDrop").hover(function(){
    $('.deltaDrop ul').stop(false,true).slideDown(250);
    $('.delta').css('background-position','-61px -70px');
},function(){
    $('.deltaDrop ul').stop(false,true).slideUp(450);
    $('.delta').css('background-position','-61px 0');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: ps. I don't really want a complete answer, just point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var timer;
timer =     setTimeout(function () {
                    -- Your code goes here!
                }, 250);
```

Then you can use the  clearTimeout() function like this.

```
 clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: Excellent! That's just what I needed!

Comment: Sorry I can't 'up' your answer but I don't have enough Rep.

Comment: This answer is problematic because if you sweep the mouse back and forth, a timer will be instantiated for every mouseover and it will act crazy.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
$(".deltaDrop").hover(function(){
    $('.deltaDrop ul').stop(false,true).hide(1).delay(250).slideDown();
    $('.delta').css('background-position','-61px -70px');
},function(){
    $('.deltaDrop ul').stop(false,true).show(1).delay(450).slideUp();
    $('.delta').css('background-position','-61px 0');
});
```

[.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only works when you're dealing with the animation queue. `.hide()` and `.show()` without arguments don't interact with the animation queue. By adding the `.hide(1)` and `.show(1)` before the `.delay()` makes the slide animations wait on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.deltaDrop ul').slideDown()
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, unrefactored:

```
$(".deltaDrop")
  .hover(
    function()
    {
      var timeout = $(this).data('deltadrop-timeout');

      if(!timeout)
      {
        timeout =
          setTimeout(
            function()
            {
              $('.deltaDrop ul').stop(false,true).slideDown(250);
              $('.delta').css('background-position','-61px -70px');
              $('.deltaDrop').data('deltadrop-timeout', false);
            },
            250
          );
        $(this).data('deltadrop-timeout', timeout);
      }
    },
    function()
    {
      var timeout = $(this).data('deltadrop-timeout');
      if(!!timeout)
      {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('.deltaDrop').data('deltadrop-timeout', false);
      }
      else 
      {
        $('.deltaDrop ul').stop(false,true).slideUp(450);
        $('.delta').css('background-position','-61px 0');
      }
    }
  );
```